# Get WRPCTokenURL from CRM attachment using jquery

Tags: jquery, dynamics-crm-2015

I need to get the `WRPCTokenUrl` from the clip below:

```
<span id="crmAttachment" 
    tabIndex="0" 
    class="attachment" 
    title="Click to open" 
    attachmentId="{868FCA8E-C992-E511-9419-0050569E70E2}" 
    attachmentType="5" 
    merchantId="{D6DF1974-4CD8-DE11-BCF5-00155D010600}" 
    userId="{9D98CF02-A484-E511-9418-0050569E70E2}"  
    url="/Activities/Attachment/download.aspx"
    "WRPCTokenUrl="Data I want to get"" 
    HideOpenButton="0">
```

This is what I have so far using jquery 1.9.1:

```
$.get(URL, function (data) {            
    var tempDom = $('<output>').append($.parseHTML(data));
    var WRPCTokenElement = $(tempDom).find("crmAttachment");
    if (WRPCTokenElement) {
        var WRPCTokenUrl = WRPCTokenElement.attr("WRPCTokenUrl");
        if (WRPCTokenUrl) {
            URL = WRPCTokenUrl;
            window.open(URL);
        }               
    }
}, "html");
```

But the problem appears to be with the extra quotes before and after the "WRPCTokenURL" attribute which I do not have the ability to change. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly the HTML is invalid; there are mis-matched double quotes around the attribute. also note that inventing your own attributes is invalid. If you need to store custom data with an element, use `data-*` attributes:

```
<span id="crmAttachment" 
    tabIndex="0" 
    class="attachment" 
    title="Click to open" 
    data-attachmentId="{868FCA8E-C992-E511-9419-0050569E70E2}" 
    data-attachmentType="5" 
    data-merchantId="{D6DF1974-4CD8-DE11-BCF5-00155D010600}" 
    data-userId="{9D98CF02-A484-E511-9418-0050569E70E2}"  
    data-url="/Activities/Attachment/download.aspx"
    data-WRPCTokenUrl="Data I want to get" 
    data-HideOpenButton="0">
```

Your JS then just has a couple of issues. The `crmAttachment` selector is missing the `#` operator, you should check the `length` property of the jQuery object to see if any elements matched the selector, and you now should use the `data()` method to get the information you need:

```
$.get(URL, function (data) {            
    var tempDom = $('<output>').append($.parseHTML(data));
    var wrpcTokenElement = $(tempDom).find("#crmAttachment");
    if (wrpcTokenElement.length) {
        var wrpcTokenUrl = wrpcTokenElement.data("wrpctokenurl");
        if (wrpcTokenUrl) {
            window.open(wrpcTokenUrl);
        }               
    }
}, "html");
```

[**Example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/tLgqjph2/)

Note that the attribute name given to `data()` is lowercase due to the way jQuery caches the object.